# IOS Push Notification - Failed with Production Profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

[image]

Our team is developing an app with push notification feature.

The development went well and messages were delivered to our testing device. So far so good.

Then we decided the app was ready for rollout and moved to production test.

Things started to go wrong, we created a new provisioning profiles, updated related http request links and ssl certificate, etc.

When all the setup was done, we tried to build the project to our testing device again, and it failed with the attached error message.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: check that your .p12 is matched with your production provisional profile, if is same , just  restarting your Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Restart xcode and then try to build

or

refresh profiles in xcode and then try to build

```
  XCode > Preferences > Accounts > Click on your DEV ACCOUNT > View Details button (bottom right) > Signing Iden/PPs screen appears > hit Refresh.
```

Comment: Tired, no luck. Thanks.